# Maximum call stack size exceeded - Method gets called repeatedly

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery

I have the following piece of code -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var objDemo = new DemoPlugin();
   objDemo.Insert();
});

var DemoPlugin = (function() {
    function DemoPlugin() {
        this.Name = "XXXXX";
        this.Email = "xxxxx@osmosys.asia";
    }

    var makeAjaxCall = function(methodToCall, dataTo, msg, cB, scMsg, errMsg) {
        var wpAction = 'handleRequests';
        msg = msg ? msg : "Loading...";
        scMsg = scMsg ? scMsg : "The operation was successful.";
        errMsg = errMsg ? errMsg
                : "There was an error while perfomring the operation.";
        var dataToSend = {
            action : wpAction,
            dataToProcess : {
                method : methodToCall,
                data : dataTo
            }
        };
        try {
            jQuery.post(WpAjax.ajaxurl, dataToSend, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (cB) {
                    cB(response);
                }
                return;
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

    DemoPlugin.prototype.Insert = function() {
        console.log(this);
        makeAjaxCall('insertContacts', this, 'Inserting Contact');
    };

    return DemoPlugin;
}());
```

When I run this piece of code without the `jQuery.post` part, the function runs fine. But when the `jQuery.post` is included the, Prototype `Insert` method is called twice and so is the makeAjaxCall method which is then causing the error mentioned. Second time the `Insert` and `makeAjaxCall` methods are called this refers to the window object.

I'm not able to pinpoint the reason for this. Is there anything wrong with my code design?

`WpAjaxUrl` is defined by the WordPress `wp_localize_script`

---

**Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kv6b/3/) reproducing the issue.**

If you notice, before the ACCESS ORIGIN ERROR in the `Insert` method, I'm logging `this`. The first time it refers to DemoPlugin which is correct, but the second time it refers to the window object.

Comment: What are you expecting `dataToSend.dataToProcess.data` to be? What's an example value?

Comment: @Matt, right now I'm passing the DemoPlugin object as a parameter. If you notice inside the `Insert` prototype call, I'm passing `this`

Comment: @Matt, Added [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kv6b/3/)

Comment: You didn't answer my question (I see that is what it is *doing* but I asked you what you are *expecting* in terms of an example). In any case, I believe what is happening is that when the `Window` object is set to `this` it contains a reference to itself. When the POST goes to serialize it, it enters into a recursive loop, hence the stackstack overflow. Solution: Check the type of `this` and only make the call if it is actually a `DemoPlugin`.

Comment: @Matt, a javascript object with two properties - `name` and `email`? Something like this `{ name : 'Abijeet' , email : 'abijeet@gmail.com' }`. And yes, I could do that but why is `Insert` getting called the second time anyways?

Comment: When I try to exec your jsfiddle, my browser crashes. I was happy to see a "too much recursion on ... obj.name ..." shortly. Uncommenting the line `data : dataTo` solves that problem. I think you have an infinite recursion while serialising `this` in `makeAjaxCall`. Updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8kv6b/6/

Comment: Please provide a [truncated] stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Insert` is a member of `DemoPlugin`, it is invoked by `jQuery.post`.

Modifying your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3t6Vs/) demonstrates this. Here, we are not even calling `Insert` directly. Instead, it is called by jQuery.post:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var objDemo = new DemoPlugin();
    jQuery.post('/echo/json/',objDemo);
    //objDemo.Insert();
});
```

The console proves that `Insert` is still called:

```
In Insert: Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
```

When `jQuery.post` tries to convert `this` to a JSON string, it appears to be invoking `Insert`. This is done by the `Window` object which would explain why it is called repeatedly since `Window` contains a reference to itself. Trying to `stringify` an object that references itself leads to infinite recursion.

The easiest way to fix this perhaps is to write `Insert` as a non-member function.